# CSS nth-child doesn't work on dynamically hidden element [AngularJS]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, dynamic, css-selectors

I'm trying to implement ***CSS*** `nth-child` on every number of elements. **If a certain number is reached** I want to **hide the first element** and make it reappear if the number reduces again.

The problem is that somehow the `nth-child` still counts the **hidden element** and thus wrongly implements the styling. Is this a bug or am I doing it wrong?

*NOTE: The same thing also happens if I use jQuery*

http://jsfiddle.net/bedex78/uZ5wn/23/

**The View:**

```html
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="TheCtrl">

        <p>Amount to add: <input type="text" ng-model="amount" ng-init="amount=1"></p>

        <div class='holder'>
            <div ng-class='elements.length < 6 ? "inside" : ""'
                 ng-hide="elements.length >= 6">
                <button class='button' ng-click="add(amount)">Add more</button>
            </div>
            <div class='inside' ng-repeat="(k,v) in elements">
                {{ $index }} <a href="" ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**The JS (AngularJS):**

```js
function TheCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.elements = [{id:1},{id:2}]

    $scope.add = function(amount) {
        for (i=0; i < amount; i++){
            $scope.elements.push({id:$scope.elements.length+1});
        }
    };

    $scope.remove = function(index) {
        $scope.elements.splice(index, 1);
    };

}
```

**The CSS:**

```css
.holder {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.inside {
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.inside:nth-child(3n+1) {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.inside a {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because hidden element is still in DOM. So it is count as a child and styles applied accordingly.

You can try to use `ng-if` instead of `ng-hide`. It will make `div` disappear from DOM and styles will work fine.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kc98x19j/)

Comment: That's great. Thanks!

Comment: Though I'm wondering, even if the `div` is still in the DOM, **why doesn't the removal of the `class` affect it**?

Comment: Because you're not changing anything about it except its class. That element is still there, in the same position.

Comment: `.cls:nth-child(3n+1)` basically selects element if its position matches 3n+1 and its class is `cls`. Not every `3n+1` element with class `cls`.